# the infinite product bessel function product representation

Tags: calculus

I see in some paper that bessel function can be represent as
$$J_p(x)=\prod _{k=1}^{\infty } \left(1-\frac{x^2}{\left(j_{p,k}\right){}^2}\right)$$ using his zeros
but this i not correct at all
so that for example i calculate that  for p=1/4
$$J_{\frac{1}{4}}(x)=\frac{\sqrt[4]{x} \prod _{k=1}^{\infty } \left(1-\frac{x^2}{\left(j_{\frac{1}{4},k}\right){}^2}\right)}{\sqrt[4]{2} \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)}$$
it is Correct??
ok it is not entire if p it is not a integer but

$$J_2(x)=\frac{1}{8} x^2 \prod _{k=1}^{\infty } \left(1-\frac{x^2}{\left(j_{2,k}\right){}^2}\right)$$ and  it seem works fine

Comment: Weierstrass factorization applies to entire functions. While $J_2(x)$ is an entire function, $J_{1/4}(x)$ is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. The leading term of $J_p(x) = (x/2)^p/\Gamma(p+1)$ is, in general, if $p\ge 0$, so the product formula is missing that factor.